# Error Preserved While Login in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I've created migration with new column `isBan` for users but when I want to get not banned users, I have this error when login in my page:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'isBan' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
>   antonio.palermo21@gmail.com and `isBan` = 0 limit 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have such column (this is what error says).

If you created migration that adds this column to table, make sure you have run:

```
pho artisan migrate
```